# SEGV signal while getting the length of a string

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault

I am having this following code :

```
int Class::set(const char *  id_tran_typ_)
{
        char *trimmed_id_tran_typ_ = NULL;
        trimString(id_tran_typ_, &trimmed_id_tran_typ_);
        int len = strlen(trimmed_id_tran_typ_);
        if (len < 1)
                _id_tran_typ = DEFAULT_STRING;
        else
                _id_tran_typ = id_tran_typ_;
        delete[] trimmed_id_tran_typ_;
        trimmed_id_tran_typ_ = NULL;
        return SUCCESS;
}
```

Here I am getting a SEGV signal at int `len = strlen(trimmed_id_tran_typ_);`

The trimString function is something like this :

```
char *trimString(const char *sP_, char **dP_)
{

        *dP_ = NULL;

        if (sP_ == NULL)
                return *dP_;

        const char *lastPos = (char *)&sP_[strlen(sP_)];
        const char *startPos = (char *)sP_;
        const char *endPos = lastPos;

        int len = strlen(sP_);

        for (; endPos != sP_; endPos--)
        {
                if (*(endPos - 1) != ' ')
                {
                        len = endPos - sP_; // *endPos = '\0';
                        break;
                }
        }
        if (len == 0) // if (*endPos != '\0')
        {
                *dP_ = new char[1];
                *dP_[0] = '\0';
                return *dP_;
        }
        for(; startPos < endPos; startPos++, len--)
        {
                if (*startPos != ' ')
                        break;
        }
        if (startPos == endPos)
        {
                *dP_ = new char[1];
                *dP_[0] = '\0';
                return *dP_;
        }

        *dP_ = STRDUP(startPos, len);
        return *dP_;
}
```

Now my question is obvious that why am I getting a segmentation fault here.

Is it because I am not receiving the string in the `set()` function sent in by the `trimString()` function ?

---

This is how the `STRDUP()` looks like :

```
char *STRDUP(const char *sP_, const int len_)
{
        if (! sP_)
                return NULL;
        else if (len_ < 1)
                return NULL;

        char *newP = new char [ len_ + 1] ;
        memset(newP, '\0', len_+1);
        strncpy(newP, sP_, len_);
        return(newP);
}
```

Comment: You left out the most important part: `STRDUP`.

Comment: Besides `STRDUP` as was mentioned, how are you calling `set`?

Comment: How is the calling of set() linked with the segmentation fault here ?

Comment: What debugging have you performed? Is _all_ of this code directly causing the segfault? I doubt it. http://sscce.org

Comment: Actually this `set()` function is getting called from the constructor of the `Class` class. Basically the `Class` object is being pushed into a queue. The first object is getting pushed fine. But it is the second one onwards that is causing all the pain. The constructor is getting invoked like this somewhere `Sample = new Class();`

Answer (score 0):

Either your `STRDUP` function returns a null pointer or `id_tran_typ_` is a null pointer.

Comment: This is how the STRDUP function looks

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the `Class::set` method is being called with `id_tran_type_` set to `NULL`. You could fix this by checking if the `trimmed_id_tran_typ_` value is `NULL` before checking the length.

```
int Class::set(const char *  id_tran_typ_)
{
    char *trimmed_id_tran_typ_ = NULL;
    trimString(id_tran_typ_, &trimmed_id_tran_typ_);
    if (!trimmed_id_tran_typ_ || strlen(trimmed_id_tran_typ_) < 1)
        _id_tran_typ = DEFAULT_STRING;
    else
        _id_tran_typ = id_tran_typ_;
    delete[] trimmed_id_tran_typ_;
    trimmed_id_tran_typ_ = NULL;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```